# Confusion in Sampling using the IP algorithm (Bishop PRML)

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, conditional-probability, monte-carlo, expectation-maximization

I'm reading Bishop's PRML p. 537 and I don't understand one piece of the IP (data augmentation) algorithm. Namely, the part that says "we use the samples $\{\mathbf{Z}^{(l)}\}$  obtained in the I step to compute a revised estimate of the posterior distribution over $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ given by:"
$$p(\boldsymbol{\theta}|\mathbf{X}) \approx \frac{1}{L}\sum_{l=1}^{L}p(\boldsymbol{\theta}|\mathbf{Z}^{(l)},\mathbf{X})$$

But isn't $\mathbf{Z}^{(l)}$ sampled from $p(\mathbf{Z}|\boldsymbol{\theta},\mathbf{X})p(\boldsymbol{\theta}|\mathbf{X})$ (the sampling distribution in the I step), and not $p(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{X})$?

I'm trying to reconcile this considering the above summation is a stochastic approximation of 
$$p(\boldsymbol{\theta}|\mathbf{X}) = \int p(\boldsymbol{\theta}|\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{X})p(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{X})\textrm{d}\mathbf{Z}$$

and the approximation would only work if $\mathbf{Z}^{(l)}\sim p(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{X})$.

Thanks